# Conditional operation on specific variable values

Tags: r

I'm looking for a way to write a conditional operation on a variable within a dataframe by *variable values* and I can't quite wrap my head around how to go about it.

Say I have the following daily data for animal shelter intake:

```
shelters <- data.frame(
    date = rep(seq(as.Date("2014-02-01"), length=10, by = "1 day"),10),
    animal = sample(c("dog","cat","goldfish"), 100, replace = T),
    intake = sample(1:10, 100, replace = T))
```

I want to set up a rule to augment the dataframe so that when the running sum of intakes for a certain animal in the "animal" variable reaches a given value, every "intake" after the date at which it reaches that given value is turned to 0.

Let's say the max value for each animal is as follows:

```
dog = 90
cat = 100
goldfish = 85
```

My inclination is to use a cumsum, but how do I go about specifying the specific animal values within the cumsum formula?

Comment: Tulia. If the max. values are stored in a vector arranged in the same order as the animal column, `v1 <- c(90,100, 85);  indx <- setNames(v1, unique(as.character(shelters$animal)))[as.character(shelteres$animal)]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
 shelters$indx <- setNames(c(90,100,85), c("dog", "cat", "goldfish") )[as.character(shelters$animal)]

 library(dplyr)
 shelters%>% 
 arrange(date, animal)%>%
 group_by(animal) %>% 
 mutate(Sum=cumsum(intake), intake=ifelse(Sum >indx, 0, intake)) %>% 
 select(-indx, -Sum) %>%
 head()
 #       date animal intake
 #1 2014-02-01    cat      1
 #2 2014-02-01    cat      4
 #3 2014-02-01    cat      2
 #4 2014-02-01    cat      2
 #5 2014-02-01    dog      5
 #6 2014-02-01    dog      9
```

#### Update

If you want to have the sum to be the same as max value

```
  res <- shelters %>%
  arrange(date, animal)%>% 
  group_by(animal) %>% 
  mutate(Sum=cumsum(intake), index2 = ifelse(Sum>indx,intake-(Sum-indx), intake),
            intake= ifelse(index2<0,0, index2))%>% 
  select(-indx, -Sum, -index2)

  res %>% summarize(Sum=sum(intake))
  #Source: local data frame [3 x 2]

  #    animal Sum
  #1      cat 100
  #2      dog  90
  #3 goldfish  85
```

Comment: That appears to work, thanks akrun. My only concern is that in reality, the dataset is MUCH larger, with hundreds of variable values and max values for each. But, I suppose I can work around that by matching a lookup list of max values to each variable name, similar to how you did with the indx variable

Comment: @Marc Tulia.  I think `dplyr` should work fine with large datasets.  If not, you can try `data.table`

Comment: I'm a bit stumped on this approach now that I've tried to implement it. The problem I'm running into is that, say "cat" index = 100. I want to record all intakes so that when I sum them up, they equal 100 and nothing more or less. But, say the Sum = 95 and the next number in line is 10. the cumsum function won't count up to 100 in this case; it will cut the summing off at 95. How do I get around that?

Comment: @Marc Tulia.  I think it is not very clear about how you wanted in the example you cited.  If Sum=95 and the next number is 10, the current approach makes it 0.  Do you want the next number to be 105 or 100 and after that all 0s??

Comment: Akrun, sorry about that. I'd want it to be 100 and after that, all 0s. So I want it to keep counting "intake" right up to AND including its index --even if that means splitting the next intake number--, then 0s.